# Slow network performance in win 7 when reading winXP share

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares

I have a windows share on a Windows XP (SP3) that is mapped as a network drive on multiple XP and win 7 workstations. When I try to start a program from that network drive on XP workstations it starts instantly whereas when we try to start the same program from win 7 computers it starts very slowly (sometimes it needs up to 5 minutes to start a program).

Browsing the directory with mentioned program is also slow in win7. Directory contains about 5000 items but in winXP content of network dir is shown immediately while in win7 it needs about 15 seconds to show all the files.

These problems occur on all win7 workstations and on multiple networks. I guess there must be some setting or switch but I can't find one.